# Dynamically created input value in div does not work currently jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I set jquery and bootstrap collapse for dynamic content. When I type some value for the title it's copied for all dynamically added titles. I try to use a personal id for any titles and inputs but it's not helpful. How can I find and solve this problem?

Title goes heare

```
<span id="accordioninnertitle" class="experience_title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exp_1"></span> (<em class="exp_start"></em> - <em class="exp_end"></em>)
```

Thanks, Advance.

HTML

```
<div class="wt-tabscontenttitle wt-addnew">
    <h2>Add Your Experience</h2>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add_experience">Add New</a>
</div>
<ul class="wt-experienceaccordion accordion" id="experience_wrapper">
    <li id="experience_list">
        <div class="wt-accordioninnertitle">
          Title goes here
            <span id="accordioninnertitle" class="experience_title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exp_1"></span> (<em class="exp_start"></em> - <em class="exp_end"></em>)
            <div class="wt-rightarea">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wt-addinfo wt-skillsaddinfo" id="accordioninnertitle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exp_1" aria-expanded="true">
                    <i class="lnr lnr-pencil"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wt-deleteinfo">
                    <i class="lnr lnr-trash" id="remove_experience"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wt-collapseexp collapse hide" id="exp_1" aria-labelledby="accordioninnertitle" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="wt-formtheme wt-userform">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-half">
                        <input type="text" name="organisation" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Title" id="experience_organisation" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-half">
                        <input type="date" name="start" class="form-control" placeholder="Starting Date" id="experience_start" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-half">
                        <input type="date" name="end" class="form-control" placeholder="Ending Date *" id="experience_end" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-half">
                        <input type="text" name="position" class="form-control" placeholder="Position" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="descript" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Job Description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span>* Leave ending date empty if its your current job</span>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(function () {
    var experince_count = 1;
    var experince_max_fileds = 5;

    $("#add_experience").click(function (event) {
        if (experince_count < experince_max_fileds) {
            experince_count++;

            $("#experience_wrapper").append(
                '<li id="experience_list">' +
                    '<div class="wt-accordioninnertitle">' +
                    '<span id="accordioninnertitle" class="experience_title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exp_' +
                    experince_count +
                    '"></span>(<em class="exp_start"></em> - <em class="exp_end"></em>)' +
                    '<div class="wt-rightarea">' +
                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wt-addinfo wt-skillsaddinfo" id="accordioninnertitle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exp_' +
                    experince_count +
                    '" aria-expanded="true">' +
                    '<i class="lnr lnr-pencil"></i>' +
                    "</a>" +
                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wt-deleteinfo">' +
                    '<i class="lnr lnr-trash" id="remove_experience"></i>' +
                    "</a>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="wt-collapseexp collapse hide" id="exp_' +
                    experince_count +
                    '" aria-labelledby="accordioninnertitle" data-parent="#accordion">' +
                    '<div class="wt-formtheme wt-userform">' +
                    "<fieldset>" +
                    '<div class="form-group form-group-half">' +
                    '<input type="text" name="organisation" class="form-control" placeholder="Organisation Name" id="experience_organisation">' +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="form-group form-group-half">' +
                    '<input type="date" name="start" class="form-control" placeholder="Starting Date" id="experience_start">' +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="form-group form-group-half">' +
                    '<input type="date" name="end" class="form-control" placeholder="Ending Date *" id="experience_end">' +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="form-group form-group-half">' +
                    '<input type="text" name="position" class="form-control" placeholder="Position">' +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="form-group">' +
                    '<textarea name="descript" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Job Description"></textarea>' +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="form-group">' +
                    "<span>* Leave ending date empty if its your current job</span>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</fieldset>" +
                    " </div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</li>"
            );
        }
    });

    $("#experience_wrapper").on("click", "#remove_experience", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("#experience_list").remove();
        x--;
    });

    $("#experience_wrapper").on("keyup", "#experience_organisation", function (event) {
        $("#experience_wrapper").find(".experience_title").text($(this).val());
    });

    $("#experience_wrapper").on("keyup change", "#experience_start", function (event) {
        $("#experience_wrapper").find(".exp_start").text($(this).val());
    });

    $("#experience_wrapper").on("keyup change", "#experience_end", function (event) {
        $("#experience_wrapper").find(".exp_end").text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you use a class ( `.experience_title` for example ) in your change events
In this situation I mean it's better to use `data-attributes` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes ). You can use `experince_count` as value for this.

So you need a data-attribute for each organisation title, date start and date end wich will give you the index of the experience concerned. After that you need to create a "target" data-attribute ( I create three to be clearer ). And to finish you need to change your selectors in your event.

You can do the same thing with concatenating / exploding id string but it's more complicated, less clear and not very useful.

Here is my answer:

```js
jQuery(function () {
    var experince_count = 1;
    var experince_max_fileds = 5;

    $("#add_experience").click(function (event) {
        if (experince_count < experince_max_fileds) {
            experince_count++;

            $("#experience_wrapper").append(
                '<li id="experience_list">' +
                    '<div class="wt-accordioninnertitle">' +
                    '<span id="accordioninnertitle" class="experience_title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target-title="' +
                    experince_count +
                    '"></span>(<em class="exp_start" data-target-date-start="'+experince_count+'"></em> - <em class="exp_end" data-target-date-end="'+experince_count+'"></em>)' +
                    '<div class="wt-rightarea">' +
                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wt-addinfo wt-skillsaddinfo" id="accordioninnertitle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exp_' +
                    experince_count +
                    '" aria-expanded="true">' +
                    '<i class="lnr lnr-pencil"></i>' +
                    "</a>" +
                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wt-deleteinfo">' +
                    '<i class="lnr lnr-trash" id="remove_experience"></i>' +
                    "</a>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="wt-collapseexp collapse hide" aria-labelledby="accordioninnertitle" data-parent="#accordion">' +
                    '<div class="wt-formtheme wt-userform">' +
                    "<fieldset>" +
                    '<div class="form-group form-group-half">' +
                    '<input type="text" name="organisation" class="form-control" placeholder="Organisation Name" id="experience_organisation" data-exp="'+experince_count+'">' +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="form-group form-group-half">' +
                    '<input type="date" name="start" class="form-control" placeholder="Starting Date" id="experience_start" data-exp="'+experince_count+'">' +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="form-group form-group-half">' +
                    '<input type="date" name="end" class="form-control" placeholder="Ending Date *" id="experience_end" data-exp="'+experince_count+'">' +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="form-group form-group-half">' +
                    '<input type="text" name="position" class="form-control" placeholder="Position">' +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="form-group">' +
                    '<textarea name="descript" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Job Description"></textarea>' +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="form-group">' +
                    "<span>* Leave ending date empty if its your current job</span>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</fieldset>" +
                    " </div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</li>"
            );
        }
    });

    $("#experience_wrapper").on("click", "#remove_experience", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("#experience_list").remove();
        x--;
    });

    $("#experience_wrapper").on("keyup", "#experience_organisation", function (event) {
            value = $(this).attr("data-exp");
        $("#experience_wrapper").find("[data-target-title='"+value+"']").text($(this).val());
    });

    $("#experience_wrapper").on("keyup change", "#experience_start", function (event) {
    value = $(this).attr("data-exp");
        $("#experience_wrapper").find("[data-target-date-start='"+value+"']").text($(this).val());
    });

    $("#experience_wrapper").on("keyup change", "#experience_end", function (event) {
    value = $(this).attr("data-exp");
        $("#experience_wrapper").find("[data-target-date-end='"+value+"']").text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wt-tabscontenttitle wt-addnew">
    <h2>Add Your Experience</h2>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add_experience">Add New</a>
</div>
<ul class="wt-experienceaccordion accordion" id="experience_wrapper">
    <li id="experience_list">
        <div class="wt-accordioninnertitle">
          Title goes here
            <span id="accordioninnertitle" class="experience_title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target-title="1"></span> (<em class="exp_start" data-target-date-start="1"></em> - <em class="exp_end" data-target-date-end="1"></em>)
            <div class="wt-rightarea">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wt-addinfo wt-skillsaddinfo" id="accordioninnertitle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exp_1" aria-expanded="true">
                    <i class="lnr lnr-pencil"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wt-deleteinfo">
                    <i class="lnr lnr-trash" id="remove_experience"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wt-collapseexp collapse hide" id="exp_1" aria-labelledby="accordioninnertitle" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="wt-formtheme wt-userform">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-half">
                        <input type="text" name="organisation" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Title" id="experience_organisation" data-exp="1"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-half">
                        <input type="date" name="start" class="form-control" placeholder="Starting Date" id="experience_start" data-exp="1"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-half">
                        <input type="date" name="end" class="form-control" placeholder="Ending Date *" id="experience_end" data-exp="1"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-half">
                        <input type="text" name="position" class="form-control" placeholder="Position" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="descript" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Job Description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span>* Leave ending date empty if its your current job</span>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```